# R How to plot multiple line charts based on numeric variable

Tags: r

Hope someone can help with this, it seems like such a simple thing to do, but being relatively new to R I am struggling with it.

I have sixty trees split between two Plots("N Edge" and "S Edge"). Each tree is identified with a RecordNo that varies from 1 to 30. I sample each tree on a regular basis.

I would like to plot a line chart for each tree. I can create one chart using the line:

```
    plot(Date[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==1 ], CO2flux[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==1],main="RecordNo=1",type="l")
```

But if I try to create a loop to plot all thirty:

```
  for(i in 1:30)plot(Date[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==i], CO2flux[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==i],main=paste("RecordNo= " & i,type="l"))
```

I receive an error message:

> "Error in "RecordNo= " & i : 
>     operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"

Please can someone explain where I am going wrong and how I can create the thirty charts I need?

Ultimately I want to find the equations that describe each line in the form
`y=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3`
and find values for `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` for each tree.

Thanks

Carl

Comment: So, it seems that my syntax was not quite right. This works OK:
        for(i in 1:30){
    plot(Date[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==i], CO2flux[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==i],main=paste("RecordNo= " , i),type="l")
              }

Comment: Sparake: does it `Date` in the first argument of plot i.e `Date[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==1 ]` ? or you mean `Data`

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that my syntax was not quite right. This works OK:
        for(i in 1:30){
    plot(Date[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==i], CO2flux[Plot=="N Edge" & RecordNo==i],main=paste("RecordNo= " , i),type="l")
              }

Comment: Now to find the formula for each line